# Filter only specific keys from an external file in jq

Tags: json, select, filtering, identifier, jq

I have a JSON file with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "00001",
    "attr": {
      "a": "foo",
      "b": "bar",
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "00002",
    "attr": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
...
]
```

and a text file with a list of ids, one per line. I'd like to use `jq` to filter only the records whose ids are mentioned in the text file. I.e. if the list contains "00001", only the first one should be printed.

Note, that I can't simply `grep` since each record may have an arbitrary number of attributes and sub-attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are basically two ways to proceed:

1. read the file of ids from STDIN
2. read the JSON from STDIN

Both are feasible, but here we illustrate (2) as it leads to a simple but efficient solution.

Suppose the JSON file is named in.json and the list of ids is in a file named ids.txt like so:

```
00001
00010
```

Notice that this file has no quotation marks.  If it does, then the following can be significantly simplified as shown in the postscript.

The trick is to convert ids.txt into a JSON array.  With the above assumption about quotation marks, this can be done by:

```
jq -R . ids.txt | jq -s .
```

Assuming a reasonable shell, a simple solution is now at hand:

```
jq --argjson ids "$(jq -R . ids.txt | jq -s .)" '
  map( select( .id as $id | $ids | index($id) ))' in.json
```

#### Faster

Assuming your jq has `any/2`, then a simpler and more efficient solution can be obtaining by defining:

```
def isin($a): . as $in | any($a[]; $in == .);
```

The required jq filter is then just:

```
map( select( .id | isin($ids) ) )
```

If these two lines of jq are put into a file named select.jq, the required incantation is simply:

```
jq --argjson ids "$(jq -R . ids.txt | jq -s)" -f select.jq in.json
```

#### Postscript

If the index file consists of a stream of valid JSON texts (e.g., strings with quotation marks) and if your jq supports the `--slurpfile` option, the invocation can be further simplified to:

```
jq --slurpfile ids ids.txt -f select.jq in.json
```

Or if you want everything as a one-liner:

```
jq --slurpfile ids ids.txt 'map(select(.id as $id|any($ids[];$id==.)))' in.json
```

Comment: Thanks, can the `any` solution be used as a one-liner?

Comment: Also, for some reason `ids="$(jq -R . ids.txt | jq -s)"` gives me the usage message of `jq`, however just `jq -R . ids.txt | jq -s` works as expected. I'm using bash. I've also tried adding `-M` to remove colors, but that didn't help.

Comment: @dimid - For robustness, use `jq -s .` instead of just `jq -s`.  For those with jq 1.5, an all-in-one one-liner has been added.

Comment: Great, thanks. What finally worked for me was: `jq -R . ids.txt > ids2.json; jq --slurpfile ids ids2.json 'map(select(.id as $id|any($ids[];$id==.)))' in.json`